# Json Property takes any data type value as a String value

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have some String fields and when I send Boolean or Integer values through JSON the framework takes it as a String.

```
public class Author implements Serializable{

 private static final long serialVersionUID= -319383931931231L;

 @JsonProperty("name")
 private String name;

 private String getName()
  { return name;}

 private void setName(String name)
 { this.name=name;}

}
```

Example of JSON: {  "name" : true } 
So, name would be "true", not true.
The thing is, I don't want it to accept any other data type than String (so, if I send a Boolean or Integer value I want it to give an error).

Comment: By default, all JSON values are considered as Strings. This is your code that would transform it otherwise. That being said, you might have a hard time discard data the way you intend it, as this is really time consuming and extremly hard to find false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no some configuration parameter to disable such automatic conversion. You can write own deserializer. Check [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/796) in Jackson repository

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I solved the problem using the example you gave me the link to.

Answer (score 0):

Writing my own Deserializer worked for me.

```
    public class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String>{
      @Override
      public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext desCtx)
      {  if(jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT)
           throw desCtx.wrongTokenException(jp, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING,"Attempted to insert int");
         if(jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_FALSE)
           throw desCtx.wrongTokenException(jp, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING,"Attempted to insert false value");
         if(jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_TRUE)
           throw desCtx.wrongTokenException(jp, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING,"Attempted to insert true value");
         return jp.getValueAsString();
      }
}
```

Then I reffered it in my class with the annotation `@JsonDeserialize(using=Deserializer.class)`